# How to exclude weekends data in a whole month?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am stuck at a point where I have to exclude the weekends tickets and need to count the rest tickets(just weekdays).

Let's suppose:

```
tickets               dates
-----------           ----------
123                   04/05/2012
231                   04/06/2012
111                   04/07/2012
112                   04/08/2012 
113                   04/09/2012
```

So, In the above table we have a data for 5 days including weekday and weekend.

I just need weekday data not the weekend in my final table like this:

```
tickets               dates 
-----------           ----------
123                   04/05/2012
231                   04/06/2012
113                   04/09/2012
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't bother with datefirst. It can cause problems

```
select * from @t 
where datediff(d, 0, dates)%7 < 5
```

EDIT:
Datefirst is different from database to database. So you need to set datefirst before using 'DatePart(dw,dates)' 
of the week. That means that every time you run the script you should call that datefirst. In case you decide to put it in a function you are screwed because you can't use it inside that function. So every time you call that function you rely on people remembering that datefirst part.

My solution does not rely on the individual setting of the database.

What it does is this:

calculate the days between 0 which represent 1900-01-01(a monday) and dates.

modulus 7 of that is a daynumber between 0(monday) and 6(sunday) so less than 5 is a weekday.

Comment: +1 It's clever but I think you should explain why this works. Not obvious what `0` represents.

Comment: Clever... good word, is performance to the "traditional" way comparable?  Shooting from the hip it seems that it should be.

Answer (score 1):

You typically use the combination of set [datefirst](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx) and the [datepart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) function to filter out weekdays or weekends in a query.  You haven't given much in the way of table structure so use the following as a rough guide only.

An example would be like this:

```
set datefirst 1;  /* treat monday as first day of week */

select tickets from mytable 
    where datepart(dw,mydate) < 6;  /* select days 1 - 5 only */
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply looks good to me but what if the dates are in between 1st and 31st. we need to exclude the weekends and need to get the weekdays data only.

Comment: @Shahsra Day of the Week is different from Day of the Month... Day of the Week is 1 - 7, Day of the Month is 1 - 31.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select * From Tickets Where DatePart(dw,dates) between 2 And 6
```

Assuming Sunday is Day one

you can mess with that with `SET DATEFIRST`

Comment: but if we use this code it's only gonna show only the data between the dates 2 and 6 but what if we want the data between 1st and 31st excluding weekends?

Comment: @Shahsra Day of the Week is different from Day of the Month... Day of the Week is 1 - 7, Day of the Month is 1 - 31.

Comment: @Shahsra. Google T-SQL Date functions. There are lots, and they solve lots of problems that have been about for ages.